# Failed to instantiate component or class "yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset"

Tags: yii2, format, currency, autonumeric.js

I'm trying to make a form in yii2 accept big numbers like currency . I want the number to be seperated for example 10000000  seems like that 10.000.000 . I  search and find that there is something called auto numiric  I use it but I got this error

```
<?=$form->field($model, 'num')->widget(\extead\autonumeric\AutoNumeric::classname(), [
                'pluginOptions' => [
                    'aSep' => ' ',
                    'mDec' => 0
                ]
            ]);?>

    Not instantiable – yii\di\NotInstantiableException
Failed to instantiate component or class "yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset".
↵
Caused by: ReflectionException
Class yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset does not exist
in E:\xam\htdocs\basic\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\di\Container.php at line 507
```

if I diddn't use auto numiric

```
<?= $form->field($model,'num')?>
```

the error disappear
can any body help ????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `extead/yii2-autonumeric` requires `yiisoft\yii-bootstrap` extension which uses Bootstrap 3.

You can install missing extension through composer:

```
composer require --prefer-dist yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap
```

Or you can add it in your `composer.json` and then run `composer update` to install it.

Edit: actually, I've missed that `yii2-bootstrap4` and `yii2-bootstrap5` extensions uses different namespaces so for `yii2-autonumeric` extension to work you have to install bootstrap 3 extension.
If you can't use bootstrap 3, you should probably switch to another extension for formating values in inputs. For example [`kartik-v/yii2-number`](https://demos.krajee.com/number) allows you to set what version of bootstrap should be used.

Comment: in my composer.json I have yiisoft\yii2-bootstrap4 in the require section

Comment: @Fahd sorry, I've missed that bootstrap4 and bootstrap5 extensions uses different namespace. So you have to use bootstrap 3 extension if you want to use `yii2-autonumeric`. I've edited my answer to reflect that and suggested alternative extension for number formating in inputs.

Comment: I used     composer require --prefer-dist yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap       to download bootstrap2 and the code works thanks alot  but I  wonder how to  use  kartik-v/yii2-number. I download it via composer but I didn't know how to update my code to use it

Comment: There is a link to yii2-number extension documentation with examples in my answer. The way to use it is basically same as with AutoNumeric widget you just need to adjust class and options.